# Having problems with Facebook share

Tags: facebook

I am trying to share a link (which basically is an image). When I click on the share link nothing happens. Checked the console got this

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (OK) https://www.facebook.com/ajax/sharer/submit_page/

Tried the debugger on FB everything looks good except I get Status Code 206

Comment: Now the error is POST https://www.facebook.com/ajax/sharer/submit_page/ 500 (OK) sdxw22bscRd.js:65

Comment: What's the URL of the link you are trying to share? Can you include any code which demonstrates the problem you are having?

Comment: Ahh Sorry I can't share the link. But Hey thanks a lot for replying. I guess I found what the issue is. I am encoding the url as well which I guess is causing the issue, I tried it without encoding and it is working fine. Thanks a lot